# Simple MVC page in IIS 8 attempting to connect to Oracle 11g via Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, oracle11g, windows-authentication

Strange issue (at least I think so)

Environment

- Visual Studio 2013 .NET 4.5
- IIS 8 Defined to use Windows Authentication and ASP Impersonation
- Oracle 11g has a number of users defined as IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY

I have a very simple MVC Razor page that connects to the database as a selected user and generates them a token for use elsewhere. My Windows account is flowing around correctly as the webpage displays it.

- When I supply an Oracle username and password everything works as expected.
- When I supply an Oracle username of / and an empty password, how Oracle expects you to tell it to connect as an externally identified user, it fails with invalid username/password error.

If I RDP into the server and run the webpage with the same credentials it works as expected (as you'd expect)

**BUT**

If I now come back to the browser on my PC and retry

- When I supply an Oracle username and password everything works as expected.
- When I supply an Oracle username of / and an empty password, how Oracle expects you to tell it to connect as an externally identified user, **it now also works as expected**???

Now I'm assuming running on the server has loaded something that now makes it work, but I have no idea what it might be or how I can make it work from the client witout running on the server first.

As per normal, all and any help most appreciated

**EDIT**

I think I'm hitting a double hop issue here as the actual Oracle server is located elsewhere. Looking into it.

Comment: You might get a better response to this on [the DBA Stack Exchange site](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The issue, I think, is more MVC IIS related that Oracle but I'll ask over there too. Thanks Bob.